# trouble changing html code of a button on click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button in html:

```
<button class="addbtn"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
```

I want to change the button's html code (Icon) on click. The new html code is :

```
<button class="addbtn"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></button>
```

And I want to switch to another icon every time I click on the button.
So I used this piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".addbtn").click(function(){
            var flag = true ;
            if(flag){
                $(".addbtn").html("<button class='addbtn'><i class='fas fa-times-circle'></i></button>");
                $(".add").animate({height:'500'});
                flag = false ;
            } else {
                $(".addbtn").html("<button class='addbtn'><i class='fas fa-plus-circle'></i></button>");
                $(".add").height(60);
                    flag = true ;
                }
        });
    });
```

But it does not change the previous html class "addbtn", it will add another "addbtn" class as a child of the previous class.

How can I just change the current html code, not adding a new class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-complicating this a little. You simply need to toggle the relevant classes with `toggleClass()`. You don't need to re-write the HTML of the element, nor use any global flags. Try this:

```
$(".addbtn").click(function() {
  var $el = $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-plus-circle fa-times-circle');
  $(".add").animate({ 
    height: $el.hasClass('fa-times-circle') ? 500 : 60
  });
});
```